# React: How to convert JSON Object to Array and render it?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

I have a big local JSON file containing League of Legends champions information. I want to output random champion data (name, title, etc...). For that I'm converting it to Object and then to Array so that I could use it with map().
The issue is that when I convert it from Object to Array, I lose property names which in my mind isn't right.

Object example with all property names as in JSON file

```
champObject:
id: "jarvaniv"
key: "59"
name: "Jarvan IV"
sprite: {url: "http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/8.11.1/img/sprite/champion1.png", x: 96, y: 48}
stats: {hp: 571.2, hpperlevel: 90, mp: 302.2, mpperlevel: 40, movespeed: 340, …}
tags: (2) ["Tank", "Fighter"]
title: "the Exemplar of Demacia"
__proto__: Object
```

Converted to Array example. Please note absence of property names

```
champData: Array(9)
0: "jarvaniv"
1: "59"
2: "Jarvan IV"
3: "the Exemplar of Demacia"
4: (2) ["Tank", "Fighter"]
5: {hp: 571.2, hpperlevel: 90, mp: 302.2, mpperlevel: 40, movespeed: 340, …}
6: "http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/8.11.1/img/champion/JarvanIV.png"
7: {url: "http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/8.11.1/img/sprite/champion1.png", x: 96, y: 48}
8: "Prince Jarvan, scion of the Lightshield dynasty, is heir apparent to the throne of Demacia. Raised to be a paragon of his nation's greatest virtues, he is forced to balance the heavy expectations placed upon him with his own desire to fight on the front..."
length: 9
__proto__: Array(0)
```

This is how I used it in my MainPage.js.
As you can see I expect to have exact property names as in my JSON file so that I could output some specific data of my choice.

```
import ChampionsData from '../data/champions.json'

class MainPage extends React.Component {

render(){
const keys = Object.keys(ChampionsData)
const randomKey = Math.floor(Math.random() * keys.length)
const champObject = ChampionsData[randomKey]
const champData = Object.values(champObject);

return(
<div> 
    {champData.map((value, index) => {      
      return <div key={index}>
        <ul>
        <li>{value.name}</li>
        <li>{value.title}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    })}
</div>
  )
 }
}
export default MainPage
```

How do I need to approach this, so that I wouldn't lose actual property names?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
const arr = []
Object.keys(MyObject).forEach(key => arr.push({name: key, value: MyObject[key]}))
```

Then access like this:

```
console.log(arr[0].name, arr[0].value) //id, jarvaniv (I prefer Zac)
```

Comment: You should use `map` here - it does exactly what you want, but on one line. (Kennen is best :P)

Comment: Actually this is one of maany solutions

Comment: Seems to be working! But is it a correct way to use it like this?:
`<li>{arr[2].value}</li>`

Comment: I can't see why not

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Object.keys` method.

```
Object.keys(champ).map(
   (key) => champ[key]
);
```

or `entries` to get array of *tuples* [key, value]:

```
Object.entries(champ).map(
    ([key, value]) => ({ [key]: value })
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `Object.entries`:

```js
const champObject = { id: "jarvaniv", key: "59", name: "Jarvan IV", sprite: { url: "http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/8.11.1/img/sprite/champion1.png", x: 96, y: 48 }, stats: { hp: 571.2, hpperlevel: 90, mp: 302.2, mpperlevel: 40, movespeed: 340 }, tags: ["Tank", "Fighter"], title: "the Exemplar of Demacia" }

const obj = Object.entries(champObject)

obj.forEach(([key, value]) => console.log(key, value))
```

You could optionally map it to an object for a more readable return object:

```js
const champObject = { id: "jarvaniv", key: "59", name: "Jarvan IV", sprite: { url: "http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/8.11.1/img/sprite/champion1.png", x: 96, y: 48 }, stats: { hp: 571.2, hpperlevel: 90, mp: 302.2, mpperlevel: 40, movespeed: 340 }, tags: ["Tank", "Fighter"], title: "the Exemplar of Demacia" }

const obj = Object.entries(champObject).map(([key, value]) => ({key, value}))

console.log(obj)
```